# Why on tailwind editor form tabs do not show content of the tabs?

Tags: html, laravel, tailwind-css

My laravel admin site with tailwind has links like (my local hosting - just example how url changed) :

```
http://local-mng-products.com/admin/products/6548d4c8725689a92c0e699e/edit
```

product editor has several tabs with design like :

```
<x-app-layout>

    <x-slot name="header">
        <h3 class="page_header">
            Edit product
        </h3>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="editor_form_wrapper">
        <h4 class="editor_form_title">
            Modify fields and update product
        </h4>
        <x-custom-message />


        <!--Tabs navigation-->
        <ul
            class="mb-5 flex list-none flex-row flex-wrap border-b-0 pl-0"
            role="tablist"
            data-te-nav-ref>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a
                    href="#tabs-details"
                    class="my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
                    data-te-toggle="pill"
                    data-te-target="#tabs-details"
                    data-te-nav-active
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="tabs-details"
                    aria-selected="true"
                >Details</a
                >
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a
                    href="#tabs-assigned-subscriptions"
                    class="my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
                    data-te-toggle="pill"
                    data-te-target="#tabs-assigned-subscriptions"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="tabs-assigned-subscriptions"
                    aria-selected="false"
                >Assigned subscriptions</a
                >
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a
                    href="#tabs-image-form"
                    class="my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
                    data-te-toggle="pill"
                    data-te-target="#tabs-image-form"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="tabs-image-form"
                    aria-selected="false"
                >Image</a
                >
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a
                    href="#tabs-import-notices-form"
                    class="my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
                    data-te-toggle="pill"
                    data-te-target="#tabs-import-notices-form"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="tabs-import-notices-form"
                    aria-selected="false"
                >Import notices</a
                >
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!--Tabs content-->
        <div class="mb-6">
            <div
                class="hidden opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-150 ease-linear data-[te-tab-active]:block"
                id="tabs-details"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="tabs-details-tab"
                data-te-tab-active>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.products.update', $product->_id) }}"  id="form_product_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @method('PUT')
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $product->_id }}" name="_id">
                    @csrf
                    1111111111111111111
{{--                    @include('admin.products.form', ['isInsert' => false])--}}
                </form>

            </div>
            <div
                class="hidden opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-150 ease-linear data-[te-tab-active]:block"
                id="tabs-assigned-subscriptions"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="tabs-assigned-subscriptions-tab">
                222222222
{{--                @include('admin.products.assigned_subscriptions_listing', ['isInsert' => false])--}}
            </div>
            <div
                class="hidden opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-150 ease-linear data-[te-tab-active]:block"
                id="tabs-image-form"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="tabs-profile-tab">
                33333333333
{{--                @include('admin.products.image_form', ['isInsert' => false])--}}
            </div>
            <div
                class="hidden opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-150 ease-linear data-[te-tab-active]:block"
                id="tabs-import-notices-form"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="tabs-profile-tab">
                4444444
{{--                @include('admin.products.import_notices_form', ['isInsert' => false])--}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</x-app-layout>
```

I commented all @include blocks to simplify tasks. It was working, but at some moment tabs stopped working :
Clicking on image tab "tabs-image-form" browser url is changed :

```
 http://local-mng-products.com/admin/products/6548d4c8725689a92c0e699e/edit#tabs-image-form
```

but content of the tabs is hidden and I see default first tab and I am do not know why?
Maybe after I upgrated package.json of my site, which has :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "adldap2/adldap2-laravel": "^6.1.7",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^6.6.4",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^10.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^v10.29.0",
        "laravel/pennant": "^1.5",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.16.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.48",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.4.1",
        "mongodb/laravel-mongodb": "^4.0.0",
        "opcodesio/log-viewer": "^1.9.1",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.1",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^2.0",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^3.8.2",
        "snipe/banbuilder": "dev-master",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.59"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.9.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.13",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23.0",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.19.2",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13.3",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.25.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "*",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.4.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.6.13",
        "sempro/phpunit-pretty-print": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.3.1",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],

        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

and in tailwind.config.js :

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    variants: {
        opacity: ({ after }) => after(['disabled'])
    },

    plugins: [
        // require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')
    ],
};

// module.exports = {
//     content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}', './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js'],
//     plugins: [require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')],
// };

// module.exports = {
//     content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}', './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js'],
//     plugins: [
//         require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')
//     ]
// }
```

any ideas what is wrong and how that can be fixed to have tabs working properly?

Thanks in advance!